# Unable to Detect Change on Dynamically Generated Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

**Description:**

I'm facing an issue where dynamically generated checkboxes are not triggering the change event when clicked. To address this, I used `$(document).on("change", ".integration-event-checkbox", ...)` for event delegation. While this successfully attaches the event, I'm encountering a problem when attempting to retrieve checked checkboxes and update the URL dynamically.

Below is a simplified ( replica  not the actual code)  version of the code:
**HTML File (`index.html`):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Multiple Choice Question with URL</title>
</head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <h2>Which events would you like to include in the URL?</h2>

  <form id="checkboxes">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="optionA" value="A" > A
    </label>
    <br>

    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="optionB" value="B" > B
    </label>
    <br>

    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="optionC" value="C" > C
    </label>
    <br>

    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="optionD" value="D" > D
    </label>
    <br>

    <label for="url">URL:</label>
    <input type="text" id="url" name="url" value="xyz.com" readonly>
  </form>

 <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript File (`script.js`):**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    const $checkboxes = $("#checkboxes");
    const integration = [ {all:["push","pull"]},{all:["post","get"]},{all:["put","delete"]}]
    const $eventCheckboxes = $(".integration-event-checkbox");

    // This event handler is not being triggered for dynamically generated checkboxes
    // $(document).on("change", ".integration-event-checkbox", (e) => {
    //     console.warn("Checkbox changed");
    //     console.warn("event",e);
    //     update_url();
    //     e.preventDefault();
    //     e.stopPropagation();
    // });

    const events = display_box(integration[0].all)
    $checkboxes.html(events);

    function display_box(integration){
      const checkboxesHTML = integration.map(item => `
          <label>
              <input type="checkbox" class="integration-event-checkbox" value="${item}" />
              ${item}
          </label>
      `).join('');

          return checkboxesHTML;
    }

    function update_url() {
        const selectedEvents = $eventCheckboxes.filter(":checked").map(function () {
            return this.value;
        }).get().join(",");
        console.log("SELECTED EVENTS: ", selectedEvents);
        // Add the checked events to the URL
        const eventsParam = selectedEvents.length > 0 ? `&events=${selectedEvents}` : '';
        console.log("Events Param: ", eventsParam);

        console.log("event checkboxes: ", $eventCheckboxes);
    }
});
```

**Issue Details:**

1. The `$(document).on("change", ".integration-event-checkbox", ...)` event handler is not capturing changes for dynamically generated checkboxes.
2. When attempting to retrieve checked checkboxes using `$eventCheckboxes.filter(":checked").map(...)`, both `selectedEvents` and the `$eventCheckboxes` collection are empty.

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Dynamically generate checkboxes using JavaScript.
2. Attach a change event using `$(document).on("change", ".integration-event-checkbox", ...)`.
3. Click on dynamically generated checkboxes and observe the lack of change event triggering.
4. Attempt to retrieve checked checkboxes using `$eventCheckboxes.filter(":checked").map(...)` and notice that the result is empty.

**Expected Behavior:**

The change event should be triggered for dynamically generated checkboxes, and the code should correctly retrieve and display the checked checkboxes.

I attempted to address the issue by reinitializing the $iec variable using let instead of const. I experimented with shifting the code above and below the point of reinitialization, aiming to ensure that the variable captures dynamically generated checkboxes properly.

**Expected Behavior:**

The change event should be triggered for dynamically generated checkboxes, and the code should correctly retrieve and display the checked checkboxes.

Comment: Are you sure you are not able to detect the changes because I tried to reproduce using your code and I don't see any problem. You can see the results here - https://jsfiddle.net/fLw7keqz/

Answer (score 1):

instead of using this

```
const $eventCheckboxes = $(".integration-event-checkbox");
```

jQuery selector to a variable just use

`$(".integration-event-checkbox").filter(":checked")...`

when you declare this on top of the code with const when you call update_url() it doesn't contain the dynamically added checkboxes.

and my sugesstion is to get the checked cheboxes as follow

```
function update_url(){
  selected = new Array();
   $(".integration-event-checkbox").each(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) selected.push($(this).val())
   })
  let eventParams = new URLSearchParams({ someOtherParam: "test", events: selected.toString(),}).toString()
  console.log(eventParams)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by changing:

```js
const selectedEvents = $eventCheckboxes.filter(":checked").map(function () {
  return this.value;
}).get().join(",");
```

To:

```js
const selectedEvents = $(".integration-event-checkbox").filter(":checked").map(function () {
  return this.value;
}).get().join(",");
```

The `$eventCheckboxes` variable just doesn't have the dynamically added checkboxes yet at the point of initialization.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [FormData() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) you get only the relevant values from the form. If you filter that list for the entries named "event" you have the values.

```js
const integration = [{
  all: ["push", "pull"]
}, {
  all: ["post", "get"]
}, {
  all: ["put", "delete"]
}];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  let form = document.forms.form01;
  form.addEventListener('change', update_url);

  form.checkboxes.innerHTML = display_box(integration[0].all);
});

function display_box(integration) {
  const checkboxesHTML = integration.map(item => `
          <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="event" class="integration-event-checkbox" value="${item}" />
              ${item}
          </label>
      `).join('');

  return checkboxesHTML;
}

function update_url(e) {
  let form = e.target.form;
  let formdata = new FormData(form);
  let selectedEvents = [...formdata]
                          .filter(entry => entry[0] == 'event')
                          .flatMap(event => event[1]).join(',');
  console.log("SELECTED EVENTS: ", selectedEvents);
  let url = new URL(form.url.value);
  let params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
  params.set('events', selectedEvents);
  form.url.value = url.origin + url.pathname + '?' + params.toString();
}
```

```css
fieldset {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<h2>Which events would you like to include in the URL?</h2>

<form name="form01">
  <fieldset name="checkboxes">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="optionA" value="A" > A
    </label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="optionB" value="B" > B
    </label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="optionC" value="C" > C
    </label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="optionD" value="D" > D
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <br>
  <label for="url">URL:</label>
  <input type="text" id="url" name="url" value="https://example.com" readonly>
</form>
```